# Webpack 4 SplitChunkPlugin's maxSize vs maxInitialRequests

Tags: optimization, webpack-4, webpack-splitchunks

When setting maxSize to 100000 for example, I get more initial chunks than the value of maxInitialRequests. I get 7 (bootstrap, main + 5 vendor chunks) where as my maxInitialRequests is set to 3. My expectation is that total initial chunks should be capped at 3. Am I missing something here?

Here is my optimization configuration:

```
      {
        name: false,
        chunks: 'all',
        minChunks: 1,
        minSize: 0,
        maxSize: 10000,
        maxInitialRequests: 3,
        maxAsyncRequests: 5,
        cacheGroups: {
          vendor: {
            name: 'vendor',
            chunks: 'all',
            test: /node_modules/,
            priority: 1
          },
          common: {
            name: 'common',
            chunks: 'all',
            minChunks: 2,
            reuseExistingChunk: false,
            priority: 2
          },
          default: false
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/)

> maxSize takes higher priority than maxInitialRequest/maxAsyncRequests.
>   Actual priority is maxInitialRequest/maxAsyncRequests < maxSize <
>   minSize.